# resize image before upload from local storage in php

Tags: php, file-upload, resize

I am creating a discussion forum. there people can upload images . I need to check image width from temporary storage and if width more than 800 needs to crop . i did this following code.

```
if (is_array($_FILES)) {    
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['discussionImage']['tmp_name'])) {
        include('includes/resize-class.php');

        $sourcePath = $_FILES['discussionImage']['tmp_name'];
        $image_info = getimagesize($sourcePath);
        $targetPath = "photos/".$_FILES['discussionImage']['name'];
        $image_width = $image_info[0];
        if ($image_width > 800) {
            $resizeObj = new resize($sourcePath);
            $resizeObj -> resizeImage(278,400, 'portrait'); 
            $resizeObj -> saveImage($targetPath, 60);   
        } 
    }
}
```

but this is not working . error shows

> Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in resize-class.php on line 16
>
> Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to bse resource, boolean given
>   in resize-class.php on line 17
>
> Warning: Division by zero in resize-class.php on line 106
>
> Warning: imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in
>   resize-class.php on line 58
>
> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in resize-clas.php on line 59
>
> Warning: imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in resize-class.php on line 217
>
> Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in resize-class.php on line 228

This is the code for resize-class.php

```
 Class resize
    {
    // *** Class variables
        private $image;
        private $width;
        private $height;
        private $imageResized;

        function __construct($fileName)
        {
            // *** Open up the file
            $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);
            // *** Get width and height
            $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
            $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function openImage($file)
        {
            // *** Get extension
            $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

            switch($extension)
            {
                case '.jpg':
                case '.jpeg':
                    $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                    break;
                case '.gif':
                    $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                    break;
                case '.png':
                    $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                    break;
                default:
                    $img = false;
                    break;
            }
            return $img;
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
        {
            // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
            $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

            $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


            // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


            // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
            if ($option == 'crop') {
                $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
                //echo"1";
            }
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
        {

           switch ($option)
            {
                case 'exact':
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    break;
                case 'portrait':
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    break;
                case 'landscape':
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                    break;
                case 'auto':
                    $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                    $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                    break;
                case 'crop':
                    $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                    $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                    break;
            }
            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
        {
            $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
            $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
            return $newWidth;
        }

        private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
        {
            $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
            $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
            return $newHeight;
        }

        private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
        {
            if ($this->height < $this->width)
            // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
            {
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
            }
            elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
            // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
            {
                $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
            }
            else
            // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
            {
                if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                } else {
                    // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                }
            }

            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
        {

            $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
            $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

            if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
                $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
            } else {
                $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
            }

            $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
            $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
        {
            // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
            $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
            $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

            $crop = $this->imageResized;
            //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

            // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
        {
            // *** Get extension
            $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
            $extension = strtolower($extension); 
            switch($extension)
            {
                case '.jpg':
                case '.jpeg':
                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                        imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                    }
                    break;

                case '.gif':
                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                        imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                    }
                    break;

                case '.png':
                    // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                    $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                    // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                    $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                         imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                    }
                    break;

                // ... etc

                default:
                    // *** No extension - No save.
                    break;
            }

            imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
        }


        ## --------------------------------------------------------

    }
```

Comment: It's hard to guess what's going on without the source code for includes/resize-class.php.

Comment: Added the same file with question. Please help !

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently your call to `imagecreatefrom` returns `false` (either that or the extension of the image is not in your switch-case).

By using `@` you're suppressing errors, which makes it impossible to trace the error. I'd suggest removing it and seeing what exact error it throws.

Comment: Removed @ from   imagecreatefrom still the error is same. @tomfrio

Comment: The `imagecreatefrom..` methods return `false` on errors. Try to find out where your code is failing by dumping the `sourcePath` variable and/or checking which case of the switch is hit.